# How to increase the space of a virtual machine?

Tags: vmware-workstation

I have created a Windows Vista VMware from an ISO Image. While creating I selected 16 GB as hard disk space. But now it's saying space is not enough for installing a service pack on that. How to increase the space of virtual machine now without recreating it?

Comment: Which of VMWare's products are you talking about here?

Answer (score 2):

This won't work if have or care about snapshots from the VM.

You can use [vmware-vdiskmanager](http://pubs.vmware.com/server1/vm/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=vm&file=disks_server.7.33.html) to expand the image size.  You'll need to shutdown the virtual machine first.

Once you have the image resized, you can use your OS disk partition tool of choice to extend the partition on the disk to the new size.  If the disk you want to resize is the system partition in Windows, which it sounds like it is, you'll probably need to mount the disk in another virtual machine to resize the actual partition, or boot off of a rescue disk.

Although the link to the vdiskmanager is from vmware server 1, I believe the same app comes with VMWare Workstation.

Comment: vmware-vdiskmanager comes with the majority of VMWare's products. e.g. Workstation, Fusion, Server 1 & Server 2. However be aware that there is currently a bug in many newer versions of this tool that stop you from resizing a vmdk with snapshots. This bug has been fixed in the latest VMWare Fusion release, but as far as I am aware it is still present in the current VMWare Server 2.0 release.

Answer (score 1):

You can run something like

```
vmware-vdiskmanager.exe -x 25GB theDisk.vmdk
```

to expand the virtual disk.

Answer (score 1):

I always setup Linux VMs using LVM, then I can expand things relatively easily just be creating a new virtual disk, adding it to the volume group, extending the relevant logical volume to make use of the new space and then expand the filesystem with resize2fs.

You could probably do the same thing in Windows by having your virtual disks configured as dynamic disks instead of static.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View18A035DE-06FF-4EA6-BC77-57D431CD50DD.htm

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem recently, and found that vmware-vdiskmanager is not included with the vmware player. However, you can download the free [VMWare Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) (after registration, which is free) which allows you to expand your disk.